# How to transfer data between views using Swift Delegate pattern

Tags: ios, swift, view, delegates

I am a student studying iOS
We are implementing data transfer between views using Delegate.

But I don't understand why the data is not being passed.

Which part should I fix?

And I don't want to use segue.

Great developers, share your knowledge!

I want to send data from LoginVC to ShowCompanyVC.

```
//LoginVC Source...
import UIKit

protocol DataDelegate: class {
    func sendData(data: String)
}

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bizNumTF: UITextField!

    weak var delegate: DataDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.sendData(data: "Data")
        guard let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShowCompanyVC") as? ShowCompanyVC else { return }
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }}

}
```

ShowCompanyVC Source...

```
import UIKit

class ShowCompanyVC: UIViewController, DataDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func sendData(data: String) {
        print(data)
        testLabel.text = data
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I suggest you study first delegates/delegation. There are lots of tutorials out there. Like https://www.appcoda.com/swift-delegate/

Comment: I have to go study!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your biggest issues here that your "self.delegate" is nil for two reasons:

1. you did not assign it to anything so your param "delegate" remains nil.
2. "ShowCompanyVC" is being instantiated after the delegate func "sendData", which means you have missed your chance to assign your delegate.

I wouldn't resort to using delegation in this case and i suggest you look more into delegates/delegation as @Glenn suggested.

I would probably solve your problem much more straight forward:

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var bizNumTF: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShowCompanyVC") as? ShowCompanyVC else { return }
    vc.data = "Data"
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}}
```

}

```
import UIKit

class ShowCompanyVC: UIViewController, DataDelegate {

//MARK: - IBOutlets

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

//MARK: - Properties

var data: AnyObject?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let data = data as? String {
        self.sendData(data: data)
    }
}

func sendData(data: String) {

    print(data)
    testLabel.text = data
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In that case you don't really need a delegate.

You can send any data directly after you instantiate the ShowCompanyVC controller.

```
class ShowCompanyVC: UIViewController, DataDelegate {

   var dataToBeReceived: String? // insert here the data type you expect to receive
   ...
}

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShowCompanyVC") as? ShowCompanyVC else { return }
        vc.dataToBeReceived = "any data"
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }}

}
```

You would need a delegate if you wanted to send data back to the login view controller from the ShowCompanyVC controller.